# Two commands successfully run manually but fail when run in shell_exec(), giving TimeOut error

Tags: php, cmd, exec, exe, shell-exec

I am trying to execute two dmd commands simultaneously using PHP `shell_exec()`. One command runs Tshark for 5 seconds. The second command runs an `.exe` file. Tshark is a program which captures network packs transferring over a network interface. The second program (named mtu.exe) sends network packets from my local machine to a remote machine.

Thing is that when I run these commands *manually*, I run the first command. A moment after that, I run the second one, and all goes well and within a second or so, the expected packets are transferred by `mtu.exe` and are captured by `tshark.exe`. Everything works perfectly well.

But then when I run the following script to execute these commands, I get the following output:

```
$firstCommand = '"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe"  -a duration:5  -w capture.pcapng  2>&1';
echo $firstCommand."<br><br>";

$secondCommand = "mtu.exe -d0 -a43020008 -g43010008 -i987654321 -s"Merry Xmass"  2>&1";
echo $secondCommand."<br><br>";

echo shell_exec($firstCommand . " && " . $secondCommand);
```

***Output:***

```
"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe"  -a duration:5  -w capture.pcapng  2>&1

mtu.exe -d0 -a43020008 -g43010008 -i987654321 -s"Merry Xmass"  2>&1

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php on line 10
```

Line 10 is the line where `shell_exec()` is. The question how to fix this issue? Why is this happening?

Comment: The second command doesn't run until the first command finishes. So `tshark` won't capture the packets generated by `mtu`.

Comment: Have you tried this ? `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)`

Comment: @Barmar is there a solution for that? I need them to run simultaneously, that is in parallel

Comment: Is this Windows or Unix? `&&` is Unix shell syntax, but the rest of it looks like Windows.

Comment: On Unix you could run `tshark` in the background, then run `mtu`, then use `wait` to wait for `tshark` to finish. I don't know how to do that on Windows.

Comment: At home I am doing it in Windows. In school I have Ubuntu and I am doing it in that. You said I could run tshark in background in Unix. Are you talking about Cron Jobs? @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Run `tshark` in the background with `&` so the shell doesn't wait for it to finish before running `mtu`. Then use the `wait` command to wait for the background command to finish.

```
echo shell_exec($firstCommand . " & " . $secondCommand . "; wait");
```

This is Unix shell syntax, I don't know if there's anything equivalent in Windows cmd.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. Let me try it in Windows. If it does not work then I will install a Ubuntu in a Virtual machine and run it there. Once I have it up and running in Ubuntu, I will think of porting it to Windows.

Comment: So I have spent two days to get a Ubuntu with all the other dependencies up and running. And this does not seem to work. The packets sent by the second command are Not being captured, apparently because the second command is not executed until the first one returns. What do I do now :'(

Comment: I also tried another method to run two scripts asynchronously/concurrently/simultaneously, that also failed and I can't tell why! I posted the [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700119/why-is-curl-multi-exec-not-executing-my-scripts-at-all) and haven't got any answer either

Comment: Did you use `&` like I did, instead of `&&`?

Comment: Yes, and semicolon and wait in the end.

Comment: Hey can you take a look at my question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718834/exec-keeps-executing-the-command-again-and-again-like-an-infinite-loop-despit) ?